# why do I have compile time error in my code?

Tags: c, compilation

I have error on code and i dont understand why, someone can help me?
the error in void printArray(char* p, int len) function on the printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for (p; p < p + len; p++)
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char* msg = "hi jyegq meet me at 2 :)";
    printArray(msg, strlen(msg));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p < p + len;` will always be true unless `len` is negative, which it isn't. Please use another variable: `for (char *p2 = p; p2 < p + len; p2++) { printf("%c", *p2); }`

Comment: Just use `void print_str (const char *s) { if (!s) return;
    while (*s) putchar (*s++);
}`

Comment: Which compiler error do you get? Please make a full, verbatim, textual quote part of your [mre].

Comment: @Alex123 it's a runtime error. Don't confuse the compilation with execution.

Comment: The compiler message is _diagnostic information_; without that information you are asking others to stare at your code to actually compile it to figure out what your compiler is already telling you.  You get the best and fastest answers if you make it easy for others by providing _all_ the information available to you.

Comment: .. this kind of problem is best resolved using a debugger rather then SO questions.  Alos inaccuartely reporting an issue as a compile time error is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compile time error in GCC at least.  However this line:

```
for (p; p < p + len; p++)
```

can with appropriate settings elicit a warning in GCC at kleast:

```
main.c:6:5: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
```

However that refers to `p` in the initial expression which does nothing and is benign.  The real (runtime not compile time) issue is that the expression `p < p + len` can never be true unless `len == 0` - in which case it is always true.

```
    for( char* pstart = p; p < pstart + len; p++)
```